# Rename button by writing directly on the button using Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, rename

I have created a contex menu when you right click on a button. Inside this context menu is a button with the text "rename". What I want is when the "rename" button is pressed that the button that the contex menu was opened from gets an input where I can rename the button text that was originally on it. E.g. I right click on the button named "Awesome button", press "rename", and then I an input gets placed on the "Awesome button" button with the text "Awesome button". When I change the text to "Best Button" and press enter the input should disapear and the button text is set to "Best button" instead of "Awesome button". Is there a clean way of doing this in Vanilla Javascript? (No jQuery, etc).

If my example to too complex to understand or just poorly written in your opinion:
I want to be able to rename a button by writing DIRECTLY on it when another button is pressed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. (One thing to research: `content-editable`.)

Comment: On click, display an input that is positioned on top of the button (simple to do with position relative/absolute combination). Give that input an event handler for button press, check for enter and then change the text of the button in that handler and set the input back to invisible.

Comment: If you could share a specific code snippet that you are having trouble with, or maybe share what you have so far in jsfiddle, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @wtf-javascript If I were you I would delete you name calling comments before you are banned from the site. You agreed [to a policy](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) when you signed up and you just broke it. Remember that people here are helping you  for free. Be nice or no one will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [contenteditable](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_contenteditable.asp), click on the button and you can edit the text on it

```html
<button contenteditable>Hello</button>
```

Alternative approach

You can have rename button and when you click on that button you can make the `contenteditable = true or false`

Comment: Thanks! Great idea!

Comment: happy to help :)